# How to figure out what a keyboard shortcut is set to

Tags: keyboard

For example, I would like to know what Shift-F1 does.

I've looked in the keyboard shortcuts section and couldn't find anything.

Is there a way I can look it up? Either on my Mac, or some reference table somewhere?

I notice in the terminal, it just makes a beep sound, and in safari it does nothing at all.

the reason for it is I want to use this shortcut when I ssh into a linux machine to control byobu.

Answer (score 1):

Is this app specific or in finder?
If its finder, I dont see a shift+f1 shortcut, only control+f1

[image]